# Solr spellcheck's top suggestion is unexpected

Tags: solr, lucene, spell-checking, edit-distance

I'm using solr 4.6.1 spellcheck component for spelling suggestions. I configured it to use DirectSolrSpellChecker with default distance function and comparator, which, as I understand, means the suggestions are ranked by edit distance (primary key), followed by document frequency (secodary key).

however, for the term **papaer**, the top suggestion is **papier**, which has far less document frequency than that of **paper**. both the alternatives are 1 edit distance away from **papaer**.

Is this a bug or a quirk of the edit distance algorithm I don't understand?

my spellcheck config:

```
<!-- a spellchecker built from a field of the main index -->
<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">default</str>
  <str name="field">spellfield</str>
  <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
  <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
  <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
  <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
  <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
  <!-- Sort Results by frequency -->
  <str name="comparatorClass">score</str>
  <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
  <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
  <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
  <int name="minPrefix">0</int>
  <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
  <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
  <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
  <int name="minQueryLength">3</int>
  <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
  <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
  <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents-->
  <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">2</float>
</lst>
```